# Double series analysis evaluation

Tags: real-analysis

I try to calculate numerically the following serie
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} (j+k)!$$
I try Borel Transform but I do not get any result, Mathematica and Maple can not sum this series .
Althought Maple can do other sum as
$$ \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} \log (j+k+1)=-0.265214374217129130274128348$$
What method use?? Euler??
but Mathematica do not
Anyway ,I being workig in a method for sum the above sum and gives
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} (j+k)!=0.403636551846321094651583$$
but I could not test it

Comment: The summands do not approach zero...

Comment: The internal sum goes to $(-1)^k$ times infinity, so the series does not have a real value.

Comment: Sorry I correct an error

Comment: You do understand what it means to have an infinite sum like this actually successfully be able to be evaluated, right?  That the sequence of partial sums must converge... and in order for that to happen we must be adding smaller and smaller terms to the end, but your terms don't get smaller at all.  Are you sure you don't mean to have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{(j+k)!}$ instead?  That, at least, will converge.

Comment: becareful the following sum it is a classical$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k k!=e \Gamma (0,1)$$ and converge  as Borel Summation

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for comments.*

Just out of curiosity, I tried to look at the partial sum
$$S_n=\sum _{k=0}^{n } \sum _{j=0}^{n } (-1)^{j+k} (j+k)!$$ For the inner summation, a CAS gives
$$\sum _{j=0}^{n } (-1)^{j+k} (j+k)!=$$ $$  (-1)^{k+n} e\Gamma (k+n+2) \Gamma (-k-n-1,1)+ (-1)^k e\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (-k,1)$$  but nothing for $S_n$.

Computing  for a few values of $n$, the $S_n$ make the sequence
$$\{1,17,533,32021,3006821,408778661,76017800261,18546246275141,\cdots\}$$ which is not found in $OEIS$.

What it seems is that, more or less,

$$S_n \sim k \,(n!)^{5/2} \qquad \text{with} \qquad k\sim 10$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is interesting but keep in mind that the sum in alternate questions and therefore in infinity many things can happen and it can always be extended to an analytical region, that is, attribute and value to sums in principle divergent, in this case the Difficulty is great because the cas do not allow calculating its value with the known algorithms for Example $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} (j+k+1)^2=-\frac{1}{8}$$